# xpath query for find path in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
<HotelList>
  <HotelSummary>
    <hotelId>247331</hotelId>
    <name>The Accord</name>
    <RoomRateDetailsList>
      <RoomRateDetails>
        <roomTypeCode>200052939</roomTypeCode>
        <rateCode>200309117</rateCode>
        <RateInfos size="1">
          <RateInfo rateChange="false" promo="true" priceBreakdown="true">
            <RoomGroup>
              <Room>
                <numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>
              </Room>
            </RoomGroup>
            <ChargeableRateInfo total="103.01" surchargeTotal="26.52" nightlyRateTotal="76.49" maxNightlyRate="76.49" currencyCode="USD" commissionableUsdTotal="76.49" averageRate="76.49" averageBaseRate="101.99">
          </ChargeableRateInfo>
        </RateInfo>
      </RateInfos>
    </RoomRateDetails>
  </RoomRateDetailsList>
</HotelSummary>
</HotelList>
```

Hello friends,
    I need to display values of `<numberofresults>` & `<chargeablerateinfo>` node in xpath
or simpleXML plz give me how to access those elements.
   I used  this code

```
  foreach($item ->('RoomRateDetailsList/RoomRateDetails/RateInfos/RateInfo /RoomGroup/Room/') as $items){
     echo $item->numberofresults;
  }
```

but it's not working
plz give me suggestion or full coding
thanks in advance

Comment: display values for numberofresults and chargeableinfo

Comment: azarudeen ajees, Was my answer useful to you? If so, please, *accept* it (by clicking on the check mark next to the answer).

Comment: Your answer helped me but i am not find the check mark near it plz instruct

Comment: Visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and expand the section (click on "show more" at the end of the "how do I ask..." section). Then the last picture of the expanded section shows how to accept an answer.

Comment: i clicked the tick mark check it mr.Dimitre Novatchev

Comment: azarudeen ajees, Your appreciation is welcome.

Comment: can you help me for autocomplete text box using ajax json for hotel booking.This will display hotel city name by using json api

Comment: XSLT, up to and including version 2.0 doesn't process JSON objects. Such question would be more appropriate for tags "json", "javascript" and "jquery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to display values of `<numberofresults>` &
>   `<chargeablerateinfo>` node in xpath or simpleXML plz give me how to
>   access those elements.

**In the provided XML document there is no element named `numberofresults`** -- you probably mean `numberOfAdults`.

**This XPath expression**:

```
//RateInfo/RoomGroup/Room
```

selects any `Room` element that is a child of a `RoomGroup` that is a child of any `RateInfo` element in the XML document.

**This XPath expression**:

```
//RateInfo/RoomGroup/Room/numberOfAdults
```

selects the `numberOfAdults` children of the elements selected by the previous expression.

**And this XPath expression**:

```
//RateInfo/ChargeableRateInfo
```

selects the `ChargeableRateInfo` element associated with a `RoomGroup`

**So, in your code you might want to do something like this**:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

$rateInfos = $xml->xpath('//RateInfo');                
foreach ($rateInfos as $rateInfo) 
{    
   $rooms = $rateInfo->xpath('RoomGroup/Room');   

   foreach ($rooms as $room)
    {
      echo $room->numberOfAdults; 
    }

  $chargeableRateInfo = $rateInfo->xpath('ChargeableRateInfo');   

  // Do whatever is wanted with $chargeableRateInfo               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$rooms = $xml->xpath('//Room');
foreach ($rooms as $room) {
     echo $room->numberOfAdults;
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: How to access attributes of ChargeableRateInfo in xpath php plz help it